# C# generic 2D array as return type

Tags: c#, generics, multidimensional-array

Problem: I am trying to create a method that returns a 2D array. Depending on the condition, a different 2D array has to be returned (one is 2D array of doubles, and other is 2D array of dictionaries). How do I declare a return type for such condition that is a bit more precise than "object"? Might be worth to note that the 2D array are instantiated elsewhere, their elements are only being given values here.

```
    public static double[,] ParseData(Dictionary<DateTime, int> dateColumnIndexDict, double[,] tableData)
    {
        ScenarioUtil.dateColumnIndexDict = dateColumnIndexDict;
        ScenarioUtil.tableData = tableData;
        return (double[,])InnerParseData();
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, double>[,] ParseData(bool isOldDictFilled, Dictionary<string, double> newNameHoursDict, Dictionary<string, double> oldNameHoursDict)
    {
        ScenarioUtil.isOldDictFilled = isOldDictFilled;
        ScenarioUtil.newNameHoursDict = newNameHoursDict;
        ScenarioUtil.oldNameHoursDict = oldNameHoursDict;
        return (Dictionary<string, double>[,])InnerParseData();
    }

    private static object InnerParseData()
    {
        /* code that assigns values to arrays elements are returns the right array */
    }
```

Scenario: I have some nested for loops in few classes that only differ in the inner for loop. They serve a similar, but not exactly the same purpose, as some fill 2D arrays of doubles, and some fill Dictionaries. I am trying to come up with a solution to refactor the code to some utility class, but I haven't come up with any decent solution, as the number and type of parameters would always differ, as well as the return type. The best solution that I came up with ended up with the problem above. Since I need to return 2 dictionaries in one of the scenarios, I've put them into a 2D array to be as close to a correct type as possible, but I still can't get pass the mutual return type for the type of a 2D array.

Any help regarding the problem, or even how to completely change the solution for a scenario is appreciated. The code is a bit messy from the trials and errors, but if the problem description is unclear I can try and extract something presentable.

For loops in question:

```
for (Int64 i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
        {
            Int64 workItemsLength = (Int64)js.ExecuteScript("return loadedData[" + i + "].WorkItem.length");

            for (Int64 j = 0; j < workItemsLength; j++)
            {
                Int64 workItemHourLength = (Int64)js.ExecuteScript("return loadedData[" + i + "].WorkItem[" + j + "].WorkItemHour.length");

                for (Int64 k = 0; k < workItemHourLength; k++)
                {
                    string date = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return loadedData[" + i + "].WorkItem[" + j + "].WorkItemHour[" +k +"].Date");
                    double hours = Convert.ToDouble(js.ExecuteScript("return loadedData[" + i + "].WorkItem[" + j + "].WorkItemHour[" + k + "].Hours"));

                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                    int value;

                    if (dateColumnIndexDict.TryGetValue(dt, out value))
                    {
                        tableData[j, (value - 1)] = hours;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

for (Int64 i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
        {
            Int64 workItemsLength = (Int64)js.ExecuteScript("return loadedData[" + i + "].WorkItem.length");

            for (Int64 j = 0; j < workItemsLength; j++)
            {
                string workItemName = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return loadedData[" + i + "].WorkItem[" + j + "].Name");
                double workItemTotalHours = 0;
                Int64 workItemHourLength = (Int64)js.ExecuteScript("return loadedData[" + i + "].WorkItem[" + j + "].WorkItemHour.length");

                for (Int64 k = 0; k < workItemHourLength; k++)
                {
                    workItemTotalHours += Convert.ToDouble(js.ExecuteScript("return loadedData[" + i + "].WorkItem[" + j + "].WorkItemHour[" + k + "].Hours"));
                }

                if (isOldDictFilled)
                {
                    newNameHoursDict.Add(workItemName, workItemTotalHours);
                }
                else
                {
                    oldNameHoursDict.Add(workItemName, workItemTotalHours);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you at least add the method signatures for the main method and the ones it calls

Comment: Dictionary <key, array>([]) could work, you could use bounds < 0 in the array for the alternative indexes... you need to determine if this makes sense to you or to use the key of the dictionary to convey that information

Comment: You should definitely post some code sample of the relevant objects, most importantly the aforementioned for loop which you are trying to unite between classes. The use of templates might be a good solution depending on the classes.

Comment: @Rhumborl I've added the signatures and edited the question a bit, seems like I have overlooked one part. Please let me know if I should add some more or if you wanted other method signatures.

Comment: @o_weisman I've added the for loops as you've requested.

Comment: From what I can tell, you will only manage to get rid of the outer 2 loop with your (in my opinion) rather forced solution. Since the data structures seem to reside in the classes and the knowledge about how to generate the data is probably also private to the class, it seems to me that you should just have a template function that runs the outer two loops and calls the inner logic member function on the appropriate class instance.

Comment: @o_weisman Can you please elaborate the last part starting from the template function? I am not sure if I understood you correctly. I believe I may have done something similar to what you said, but then again I might have completely misunderstood your point.

Comment: I meant this design pattern, I think it's suitable for your situation although I haven't really seen your classes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: @o_weisman I see. I would usually most likely opt for that solution, but I am not sure how it would work here. Since I am using all of this in making tests, I don't work with class instances, thus the reason why everything above is static. I've decided to just delegate to appropriate methods based on which overloaded method is being called. I don't know how good that solution is though, it feels like it's a more complex one, but the one that should pay off if more similar for loops are encountered. I hope that makes sense and that I haven't made some big mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to return multiple items from a method you can tuck them into a Tuple  And if you can't define an appropriate interface types you may be able to just fall back to object and sort it out later.  That's a maintainability issue, but if you know you are working with limited set of types. itt's manageable.

Comment: Are there any advantages/disadvantages of using dynamic instead of object?